Variation of monty hall
I assume the reader knows well the classic Monty Hall, and perhaps some variants. I am not sure that my specific thought variant has been asked on this forum (a quick look through monty hall related posts have not shown so) so I ask here now. Perhaps this is similar to the variation where monty forgets which door has the prize, but I am not too sure.
Let the three doors be A, B, and C. Suppose that Monty has decided on one of the wrong options to reveal, before and regardless of what you choose initially. For example, Monty knows A is a wrong option, and has decided to reveal that A is wrong, regardless of whether you first choose A, B, or C. My initial thought is that the probability then of you being right can be a maximum of 50%, and that if you pick either B or C, switching does absolutely nothing to make your probability increase.
My reasoning for this is: if you first chose A, Monty tells you that A is wrong, so you have a 50/50 for switching to the correct options of either B or C.
On the other hand if you first chose either of B or C, there is a 50% chance of having chosen the prize from the options that is not A.
...
In other words you have a 1/3 chance of making it a 50/50 (by first choosing A then switching to B or C) and you have a 2/3 chance of picking the option that Monty himself has not picked to reveal, of which there are 2 such options where 1 is right and 1 is wrong. So a 2/3 chance of landing on the 50/50 to begin with.
Seems correct to me so far but not too sure.

Now suppose your friend walks in unknowing that Monty has already set which option he will reveal as incorrect (for the sake of example, Monty will say that A is wrong). Suppose your friend chooses B. Then Monty reveals that A is wrong, and your friend declares: 'I shall switch to C for a 2/3 chance of being right!'
So for you, knowing that Monty has already been set to say 'A is wrong' before your friend chose B, you see that your friend actually has a 50% chance of being correct in the switch to C (from the explanation prior). This also makes sense because you know more information about this scenario (that Monty's decision is independent of your friend's choice, not dependent) than your friend does.
Is this reasoning correct?
This is getting long but lastly, if I tell my friend what I know, will he get mad that I reduced his chances down to a 50/50? :)

Nothing in the rules nor in Monty's selection distinguishes $B$ from $C$, so there can't be any reason to prefer one of those to the other.

Since your friend did not know that Monty was obligated to reveal a goat behind a door your friend didn't choose and offer a chance to switch (and indeed your friend cannot know this, because it's not true), his claim that he had a 2/3 chance to win is already incorrect even if you don't reveal your information.

@DavidK I'm not too sure, I think from his perspective, thinking his chances are 2/3 if he switches is valid. From his perspective the game looks like the normal monty hall problem. My reasoning is this: Suppose we play a game where I am thinking of a number, either 1 or 2. I choose a number (let it be 1) and lock it in, and now you must guess it. Suppose you guess 2. For you, you have a 50% chance of being right. For me, knowing more information than you, you have a 0% chance of being correct...

From your friend's perspective the game also looks like a common street hustle called three card monte. Did you know that the real Monty Hall never ever even once gave any of his contestants a chance to play the so-called "Monty Hall" game? He was asked about this in an interview once. The Monty Hall paradox works only when we have a clear mutual understanding of the rules that Monty must follow. The most reasonable assumption if you're given a chance to "switch" for no known reason is that it's a trick to get you to give up the prize.

And yes, of course, unequal information leads to unequal probability assessments. It has to. My point is that your friend in your story really doesn't have enough information to make a 2/3 probability assessment. It's unclear what probability assessment he can make given the information he has.

Your reasoning is sound. If Monty has to preselect the bad door that is revealed, then the game changes significantly.
Suppose that door $B$ contains the prize, and Monty preselects $A$ as the door to reveal.
If the player chooses door $A$, then Monty reveals that it is not the prize. For the player, there is now a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance that the prize is in $B$ and a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance that the prize is in $C$. This can be argued simply by symmetry.
Even if the player did not initially pick $A$, the probabilities for both $B$ and $C$ would still be $\frac{1}{2}$. We can calculate this explicitly. The posterior probability that $B$ holds the prize is, by Bayes,
$$P (B | A \text{ revealed}) = \frac{P (B \cap A \text{ revealed})}{P (A \text{ revealed})}$$
where $B$ is shorthand for the event "$B$ is the winning door" and $A \text{ revealed}$ is shorthand for the event "$A$ is the preselected bad door". The probability $P (B \cap A \text{ revealed})$ is $\left( \frac{1}{3} \right) \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{1}{6}$, since the probability of any particular door winning is $\frac{1}{3}$, and the probability that any particular door other than the winning one is preselected as the reveal is $\frac{1}{2}$. The probability that door $A$ is revealed is $P (A \text{ revealed}) = \frac{1}{3}$, because to the player, any of the three doors (equally likely, and including the initial selection) might have been selected as the reveal. This gives
$$P (B | A \text{ revealed}) = \frac{\frac{1}{6}}{\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{1}{2}$$
as desired. An identical argument applies to door $C$.
So yes, if Monty did follow this game hosting strategy, then your friend would be incorrect in claiming that switching doubles his odds of winning - even if she happened to choose a door different than the preselected reveal. The key is that she could have picked the preselected reveal. The mere fact that she didn't doesn't mean the situation is the same as the original game.
Another way to think about this is from an information theoretic perspective - after all, it is information that updates probabilities. What information is gained when Monty reveals the preselected door?

In the original game, Monty's decision depends on the player's initial choice - in particular, it has to avoid the player's choice. Since Monty can always perform such an action, the player gains no information about her initial selection, and the probability that it is winning remains $\frac{1}{3}$.
In the new game, Monty's decision cannot depend on the player's initial choice. Therefore, revealing the preselected door - which may be the player's initial choice itself - gives information about the initial choice. If it so happens that the preselected door was the initial choice, the probability of that door winning obviously goes to $0$. If not, the probability increases to $\frac{1}{2}$, because the fact that the initial choice was not the preselected door is information that the player can use.

